# intercept carriage return in a textarea

Tags: jquery

How do you catch a carriage-return in a textarea and do a form post instead of a newline in the textarea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Capture the keystroke, verify if it is enter, and then look for the parent `form` element and submit it:

```
$('#textAreaId').keydown(function (e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/igawe).

Answer (score 1):

Add an onKeyPress function to the textarea, and have it intercept Enter (character code 13) and submit the form instead.

[Here's an example](http://jennifermadden.com/javascript/stringEnterKeyDetector.html) that uses a text input instead of textarea, but it should work the same way.

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" onKeyPress="checkEnter(event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic skeleton (from the [API docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keydown)):

```
$('#textarea-selector-here').keydown(function(event)
{
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        // ...
        // different keys do different things
        // Different browsers provide different codes
        // see here for details: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html    
        // ...
    }
});
```

However, if you don't want to allow multiline input, why not just use an `<input type="text" />`?

Comment: Surely you mean type="text" :)

Comment: You may have a point TStamper because I'm having trouble with the 
$(this).parents('form').submit();
not working.